# Pandas is adding an index column even though I have specified "index_col = False", and is then unable to drop it

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, drop

As the title describes, Pandas is adding an extra column called "index" which it is then unable to find when I attempt to drop it. The CSV that I am reading in does not have an index column, but seeing as one is added when I use read_csv, I thought it would be sensible to try index_col = False

Reading in code:

`df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", usecols=["longitude", "latitude", "id", "gross_premise_area", "build_replacement_cost", "structure_cost", "content_cost"], index_col=False)`

Which results in this:

[duplicate index column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30FLC.png)

So I then try to remove the extra column:

`df.drop("index", axis=1, inplace=True)`

Which results in the following error:

`Exception has occurred: KeyError "['index'] not found in axis"`

Example of CSV:

map_use,premise_area,premise_floor_count,longitude,latitude,geomni_premise_id,geomni_building_id,premise_age,use,age_category,area,floors,zone,build_replacement_cost,gross_premise_area,structure_cost,content_cost,geom_col_vulnerabilities,id
Unclassified,86,NULL,-64.8,31.8,1234,1234,Unknown date,commercial,post-1985,86,2,city,2459,172,593,593,1234,3254654363634554654645645654

Comment: Please provide a small example of the CSV file that reproduces this error.

Comment: @CJR done. I am unable to post all the columns as they contain sensitive information but I have shown the first two columns and few rows. None of the columns are named "index".

Comment: That's not an example of a CSV file, that's a picture. CSV files are text. You should provide a minimal example of text which shows the behavior you are asking about when you run your example code.

Comment: @CJR done, apologies

Comment: You have provided an HTML table. The C in CSV file stands for COMMA. You should make a test.csv file with a small amount of data that reproduces the problem that you are encountering when you load it with the code that you have.

Comment: @CJR CSV example at the bottom of the post, apologies once again

Comment: Thanks. `df = pd.read_csv(..., usecols=[...], index_col=False)` doesn't reproduce the problem you're having with that example data (there's no extra column or multiindex as there is in your picture). Might be worth using your test data to go through your code to figure out where the problem is (it looks to me like there's a `.reset_index()` called somewhere).

Comment: Have tried this, but thanks for your help anyways

Comment: What software are you using to visualise the dataframe?

Comment: @skeuomorph: VS Code shows index as a column in its Jupyter variables viewer. I think you are using VS code here. So, continue your code without dropping the index colum. I think your code will work !

Comment: What does `print(df.columns)` return?

Comment: @Acccumulation Interestingly, df.columns doesn't show the extra index column! Maybe it's the Visual Studio Code data viewer that is adding it temporarily? I'll see if the extra index column is included when I eventually use to_csv

Comment: @Acccumulation Thank you for the most helpful (and simplest) debugging suggestion haha

Comment: Also thank you @ManjunathKMayya for your help! You are correct, it was just VSCode

Comment: And thank you @ifly6 , it is VSCode which seems to be temporarily adding an index column when I visualise the dataframe. Strangely though, it started doing this out of nowhere! I had been working the whole day without it doing this

Answer (score 1):

`index_col=0` can work if `index_col=None` or `index_col=False` isn't working. 
So do like this when reading a file if you want to drop the unwanted index column.
`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', index_col=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the error with the details you have given. You could perhaps try with the following, either separately or together :

1. Edit the Dataset in Excel/google sheet so that you only have the columns you need.
2. Just get rid of index_col = False, because the default is None anyway.

Comment: Please see @Accumulation 's comment on the main post, it seems to be something that Visual Studio Code's data viewer adds temporarily. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

There must be an index while using the data frame. If you set it to false, Pandas will add a numerical index for you.

If you don't want it while saving the data frame to a file, use `pd.to_csv(path, index=False)`.

If you want to have another column as the index, use `index_col= int / str`

The drop you're trying to use means drop a column that is called "index", and you already don't have one.

Comment: Please see @Accumulation 's comment on the main post, it seems to be something that Visual Studio Code's data viewer adds temporarily. Thanks for your suggestion though!